# ConstraintLayout doesn't match with the screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I just started my first Android Studio project and I already come with a problem :)
I search on google for the answer but didn't find my problem.

So I need your help please ^^

I download the last version of Android Studio, create a project with an Empty Activity and I came up with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZxdP.png)

As you can see my ConstraintLayout is really small and I just can't work with this.
I didn't touch anything on the project. Just to be sure I create 3 projects that have the same issue and redownload 4 time Android Studio.
On the virtual Devices, it looks correct throw: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9JAQ.png)
I put the XML code just in case it can help
[xmlcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLqSR.png)

Hope I was clear and sorry for my English ;)

EDIT: For some reason, the constraint layout fit correctly on the watch screen, but I don't want to create a watch app x) [screenshot_watchview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOI7g.png)

Comment: can you please elaborate what the error is??. I do not get it

Comment: I creat a project with a Empty Activity but as you can see on the first screenshot my ConstraintLayout is on the top left of the view and it didn't fit the screen. I tried to change the layout_width/height but it change nothing

Comment: do you want it to be full-screen without status bar that you indicated it in the first screenshot?

Comment: No, the problem is that the constraintLayout is small and when I add an over element like a textView on the blueprint I can't see it. So what I was trying to do is changing the size of the constraintLayout but it didn't change anything. Normally with the match_parent the constraint layout fit the blueprint screen no ?

Comment: Just a good advice, don't rely on the layout preview, it has some issues or glitches almost all the time , so it's always better to look how layout looks on the device

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have finally find the problem ! I'm so happy right now :D

The problem was the `AppTheme` theme that I use, I switch it with the `DeviceDefault` theme. I don't know why this theme was causing problem but now it work and I can finally work on my first Android App !

Comment: Not the best fix, actually :)

Comment: It's the only fix I found for the moment ^^

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `supportLibrary 28+` then this thing happened to me too.

and when I change the support lib version to the 27, it works.

Maybe this is a possible bug in the `support library 28+`.

Changing the `AppTheme` works like a charm if you want to stick with the `support library 28+` But if you still don't want to so Try using the `support library` below `28`.